# Rappasoft Datatables V2 (I want to show data when another table has same value column)

Tags: php, laravel, datatable, laravel-8, laravel-livewire

i want to show my products data when the user_id (foreign key) in products table same with id (primary key) on users table, i use [laravel livewire datatable](https://rappasoft.com/docs/laravel-livewire-tables/v2/introduction)

how to use this function

```
public function query(): Builder
    {
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

        return Product::query()->where('user_id', $user_id);
    }
```

in this function

```
public function columns(): array
    {

        return [
            Column::make("Nama", "name")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Deskripsi", "description")
                ->sortable()
                ->searchable(),
            Column::make("Stok", "stock")
                ->sortable()
                ->format(
                    fn($value, $row, Column $column) => $row->stock === 9999 ? '<span class="badge bg-label-success">INSTOCK</span>' : number_format($row->stock, 0, ',', '.')
                )->html(),
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the code you used is wrong
as described in this [documentation](https://rappasoft.com/docs/laravel-livewire-tables/v3/usage/the-query#content-using-the-builder-method)

this is the correct code:

```
public function builder(): Builder
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;

    return Product::query()
        ->where('user_id', $user_id);
}
```

Comment: hahahah I was less thorough in reading the documentation, thank you good people